# Talend - Need server environment variables instead of local machine

Tags: etl, talend

I'm using talend enterprise edition, I'm trying to use system environment variables as parameters for my jobs. when using system.getenv("paramname") and runnig the job, I'm getting the values from my local machine. what I need to do to to get the values from the talend server machine. The idea is to centrally add all the parameters as environment variables in the talend server and all users should use those env variables as parameters. any input is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the job being run? Locally or on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of system.getenv("paramname"), please use system.getProperty("paramname"). As system.getenv() is deprecated

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

This thread might also be of use as it could be used to accomplish similgar goals  [Reading properties from an external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737724/how-can-a-properties-file-be-created-using-talend-open-studio-data-integration/35756471#35756471) . I included screenshots and description in that answer.

This is a similar approach, but allows placing a common.properties (or other named file) for all Talend jobs running on that same job server to use. This also makes it easy to have different Talend job servers (dev, qa, production, etc), where the same jobs are installed, but they pull their correct settings from the common property file (environment dependent).

It uses the components tFileInputDelimited and tContextLoad to accomplish the task.