# Talend, How to set up context value manually, and pass it to query

Tags: sql, etl, talend

I am working with Talend Open Studio for Data Integration.
I want to create a simple job which shows all customers from database with specific city.

My job structure looks like this:

```
DbConnection -- onComponentOk -- DbInput -- row1-- tJavaRow -- row2 -- tLogRow
```

I have created a context parameter that contains specific values which are the *city* ids. I want to set the *city* manually after the job starts, and then pass it to my query on the WHERE clause. Is it possible to do this scenario with Talend? How should my `tJavaRow` code should look like?

Comment: you can not set the context after the job starts

Comment: So is there any way to execute the query with parameter I want, without setting global variable?

Comment: you can put your parameter in a property file and  can use this in your job

Comment: But I need to hardcode it's value right?

Comment: either you can give it in context or can take it from property file and put it in a global variable which can be used in your where condition

Comment: Is there any example online?

Comment: What do you mean with "after the job starts". Why that? Will the job run for hours? Why not giving a city list when the job starts as context or parameters?

Comment: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737724/how-can-a-properties-file-be-created-using-talend-open-studio-data-integration) u can use this link. this might help

Comment: I thought I can do something like in reporting tools. I execute the job, then select the parameter. Then the output shows up with my parameter included to query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually input something in a running job, you can use a `tMsgBox`. In `Component`, set `buttons -> Question`, the rest of the settings depends on you.

You will be able to input a value. That value is retrievable from the variable `RESULT` of the component.

Example with `tMsgBox_1`

```
(String)globalMap.get("tMsgBox_1_RESULT")
```